# turtlebot.eu power board and kinect

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I have a question regarding turtlebot.eu power board. I don't have any external battery so everything is power through roomba's battery. Kinect is connected on 12v dc power connector (spec at max 350mA) on the power board.

Everything works normally. I can control roomba, get video feed from kinect cameras. But I do have a problem with pointcloud data. It starts completely normal. I am receiving pointcloud normally for approximately a minute. After that it just stops. No error messages, the image just freezes. Roomba works all the time withouth problem (teleop, dashboard). It seems like that the openni freezes. Is it possible that kinect doesn't get enought power, that I should use external battery? Or maybe is there a problem with openni kinect driver?

The same problem is when I try to build a SLAM map. It works normally for about a minute then the laser topic stops posting. Since laser is build from pointcloud I think problems are connected.

Also I notice, when I watch only IR stream from kinect, the IR light on kinect flashes slowly. It is not constantly lit. Is that normal? Like that the IR camera is switching between ON and OFF.

Does anybody have the same problem? I start turtlebot with

```
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
```

and start openni with

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

Then I run

```
rosrun rviz rviz
```

to get the image.

Thank you for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30670/turtlebot.eu-power-board-and-kinect/) by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2012-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was with the lack of power for Kinect. You have to connect extra battery to the turtlebot.eu power board. After that it worked normally.

---

Originally posted by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) with karma: 460 on 2012-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0